# Unable to monitor mode and injection work on my wifi card bcm43142

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, broadcom, airmon-ng

I have dual booted my laptop with kali Linux. After working on it somehow I managed to get work my Wi-Fi. But I'm unable to start monitor mode and injection. When I execute

`airmon-ng start eth1` it Shows in driver `wl`

```
[phy0] mon0 : ERROR while getting interface flags. No such device.  
(monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

My chipset is bcm43142. After searching for this problem I found that wl driver doesn't support monitor mode and injection mode. If its true, can I change the drivers for my chipset?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a Broadcom chipset to work with linux is a royal pain, especially if you have to go the "bw43-fwcutter" route to get otherwise unobtainable firmware blob.

I was never able to get an older Broadcom PCMCIA card to do injection under Arch linux. The Arch linux wiki has a [Broadcom Wireless](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl) page that has a section for the `wl` driver. That page suggests unloading all other possible Broadcom drivers before loading the `wl` module:

```
# rmmod b43
# rmmod ssb
# modprobe -v wl
```

You should have another `xterm` open doing a tail on appropriate log. I've not run Kali linux, but something like `journalctl -f` works on "systemd" based distros, and `tail -f /var/log/messages` might work. If the Broadcom chipset is on a USB or PCMCIA device, start tailing the log before you plug it in, and keep tailing until after you do the `rmmod` and `modprobe` commands.

Here's a link to I[nstalling Broadcom BCM43142 Drivers on Kali Linux](http://www.chokepoint.net/2014/04/installing-broadcom-bcm43142-drivers-on.html) - it looks a bit sketchy to me, however.

Another possible problem is that you're running `airmon-ng` against an interface named "eth0", which is usually an ethernet (with a cable) interface. Verify that you're using the correct interface name: do `ifconfig -a` to see if some other interface names present themselves.